# How to align column in a table between the two other columns

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

Can you please help me to align the columns from Panel B between the columns of Panel A, so that First column of Panel B is between 1st and 2nd column of Panel A (2nd column - between 2nd and 3rd and so on). Below I attach the code:

```
 \newpage
 \centering

 \begin{table}[ht!] 
    \bigskip
     \centering
     \footnotesize

 \begin{threeparttable}
    \footnotesize
 \begin{tabular}{lccccc}  

 \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textbf{Panel A:} dfdfdf}\\

 \hline 

 VARIABLES  & Q &W  &E  &R  &T\\

 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5)   \\
  \hline
  &  &  &  &  &    \\

 AS & -0.001 & -0.002** & 0.006 & -0.002 & -0.004** \\


  &  &  &  &  &    \\ 

 \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textbf{Panel B:} ASASASASA}\\

 \hline 

  && (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\
 VARIABLES &&A & B & C & D \\ \hline
  &&  &  &  &  \\
 AA && -0.003 & -0.008* & -0.133 & 0.002 \\
  && (-0.428) & (-1.895) & (-1.282) & (0.337) \\
  \hline 

 \end{tabular}
   \end{threeparttable}
 \end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Please note that your usage of `\centering` outside of the `table` environment is wrong unless you want to centre the rest of your document from that point onwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{collcell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!] 
\begin{threeparttable}
\footnotesize
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\collectcell\clap}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\begin{tabular}{lcCcCcCcCc}
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textbf{Panel A:} dfdfdf} \\ \hline
VARIABLES  & Q   && W   && E   && R   && T   \\
           & (1) && (2) && (3) && (4) && (5) \\
\\
AS         & $-0.001$ && $-0.002$\rlap{**} && $0.006$ && $-0.002$ && $-0.004$** \\
 &  &  &  &  &    \\ 
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textbf{Panel B:} ASASASASA} \\ \hline
          && (1) && (2) && (3) && (4) \\
VARIABLES && A   && B   && C   && D   \\ \hline
\\
AA        && $-0.003$   && $-0.008$*  && $-0.133$   && $0.002$   \\
          && ($-0.428$) && ($-1.895$) && ($-1.282$) && ($0.337$) \\
 \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}  

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]